# filter datatable using parent id

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

[image]

I have a datatable and it has 2 fields FolderId,Parent_Id .

I want to filter all children of a parent and save it into another datatable.
I'm able to achieve this using two methods and 3 different loop, isnt there a more simple and fast way to achieve this using Linq or something.

Here is my code

```
 public DataTable ChildrenOf(string parent, DataTable dtFolders)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        if (dtFolders != null)
        {
            result = dtFolders.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow child in dtFolders.Rows)
            {

                if (child["FolderId"].ToString() == parent)
                {
                    result.Rows.Add(child.ItemArray);
                }
            }
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtFolders.Rows)
            {
                if (ChildrenOfParent(parent, dtFolders) != null)
                {
                    result.Rows.Add(ChildrenOfParent(parent, dtFolders).ItemArray);
                    parent = ChildrenOfParent(parent, dtFolders).ItemArray[0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return result;
}

public DataRow ChildrenOfParent(string parent, DataTable dtChild)
{
    DataRow drChild;
    drChild = null;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtChild.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["ParentId"].ToString() == parent)
            {
                drChild = dr;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return drChild;
}
```

Comment: I've done this task before using recursive method.  I'm not sure why you you would want to put results into a datatable.  Most times best solution is to put into a treeview.  Treeview gives really good results.  Linq doesn't work on recursive code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your search for children using Linq. Something like this:

```
public DataTable ChildrenOf(string parent, DataTable dtFolders)
{
    return dtFolders.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row.Field<String>("FolderId") == parent)
        .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

I used same method signature like in your example. Just call method with original table and parent ID. Method will return new, filtered table.

Comment: This only returns first row not all children rows of the parent

Comment: @user3178955 i have tested it with some dummy data and it is working as it is supposed to. Please, provide table structure ans/or sample data so I can test it further

Comment: Added table structure in question section

Answer (score 0):

try code

```
public DataTable ChildrenOf(string parent, DataTable dtFolders)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    try
    {
       if (dtFolders != null)
       {
          result = dtFolders.Clone();
          foreach (DataRow child in dtFolders.Rows)
          {

            if (child["FolderId"].ToString() == parent)
            {
                result.Rows.Add(child.ItemArray);
            }

            if (child ["ParentId"]!=null && child ["ParentId"].ToString() == parent)
            {
                result.Rows.Add(child.ItemArray);
                parent =child.ItemArray.ToString();
            }

         }

    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
return result;

}
```

Comment: This will not filter if the children of a parent row are not in continuous sequences